# SCIP: no reader for input file <sample.txt> available

Tags: scip

I have an input problem which need to solve with SCIP:

```
Maximize
 obj: x1 + 2 x2 + 3 x3 + x4
Subject To
 c1: - x1 + x2 + x3 + 10 x4 <= 20
 c2: x1 - 3 x2 + x3 <= 30
 c3: x2 - 3.5 x4 = 0
Bounds
 0 <= x1 <= 40
 2 <= x4 <= 3
General
 x4
End
```

I downloaded the precompiled binary files from the scip website, and here is how I tried to run:

```
./scip-3.2.1.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt.spx -f sample.txt  -s danielSettings.set
```

Any opinions why I am getting the following error?

```
danielk-2:~ danielk$ ./scip-3.2.1.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt.spx -f sample.txt  -s danielSettings.set 
SCIP version 3.2.1 [precision: 8 byte] [memory: block] [mode: optimized] [LP solver: SoPlex 2.2.1] [GitHash: c7c6c02]
Copyright (c) 2002-2016 Konrad-Zuse-Zentrum fuer Informationstechnik Berlin (ZIB)

External codes: 
  SoPlex 2.2.1         Linear Programming Solver developed at Zuse Institute Berlin (soplex.zib.de) [GitHash: 267a44a]
  cppad-20140000.3     Algorithmic Differentiation of C++ algorithms developed by B. Bell (www.coin-or.org/CppAD)
  ZLIB 1.2.5           General purpose compression library by J. Gailly and M. Adler (zlib.net)
  GMP 6.0.0            GNU Multiple Precision Arithmetic Library developed by T. Granlund (gmplib.org)
  ZIMPL 3.3.3          Zuse Institute Mathematical Programming Language developed by T. Koch (zimpl.zib.de)
  Ipopt 3.12.4         Interior Point Optimizer developed by A. Waechter et.al. (www.coin-or.org/Ipopt)

reading user parameter file <danielSettings.set>

read problem <sample.txt>
============

no reader for input file <sample.txt> available
```

Comment: Sorry dude, calling this an error seems a bit odd; the output is even more explicit than what you posted: All supported file formats are displayed, and you are prompted to select a suitable reader by extension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to rename the problem file, so SCIP knows which format it is: `sample.lp` in your case.